# Submitting form with Ajax without leaving current page

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to submit the Ajax form to prevent the page from going to another page. The script I'm using still proceeds to the other page i.e trolley1.php. The goal is to send the data to trolley1.php where it is processed but the customer stays on the product page. The script runs as fine but goes to the trolley1.php page

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('form').submit(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();

 var formData = {
        var id = $('input[name=id]').val(),
        var name = $('input[name=name]').val(),
        var price = $('input[name=price]').val(),
        var quantity = $('input[name=quantity]').val()
    };

 $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', 
        url         : 'trolley1.php', 
        data        : formData, 
        dataType    : 'json', 
        encode      : true
      });
  });
});

</script>

<?php
echo "
  <div class='col-sm-3 mt-5'>
    <form class='ajax' method='post' action='trolley1.php?action=add&id=$id'>
      <div class='products'>
          <a>$img</a>
          <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'/>
          <input type='hidden' name='name' value='$product'/>
          <input type='hidden' name='price' value='$price'/>
          <input type='text' name='quantity' class='form-control' value='1'/>
          <input type='submit' name='submit' style='margin-top:5px;' class='btn btn-info'
                 value='Add to Cart'/>      
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: You probably have an error. Look at `formData`. That's not how you [define an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects).

Comment: ^^^ You have syntax errors in your script.  *The script runs as fine* is not true.  You are encountering syntax errors in your script, which is causing it to not run.  Which then when you submit your form, is going to go to where ever the action is on the form.

Comment: Taplar, I have tried nearly every possible combination but the code still leaves the page. I have checked the syntax for the best part of 10 hours. I just can't seem to get it to stay on the same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments on the OP:

```
var formData = {
    id: $('input[name=id]').val(),
    name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
    price: $('input[name=price]').val(),
    quantity: $('input[name=quantity]').val()
};
```

Comment: this code solves the page from going to another page but now the products do not get added to the cart on the trolley.php page. I might have to look at the trolley.php code, maybe it's not picking something up. Thank you for the above code